# RPM : How to get Requires(post) list

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

Have generated rpm package with the spec file, where used Requires(post) to specify the required tools for the post installation section.

So how to get the list of Requires(post) tools list from a rpm package ? 
rpm -qp --whatrequires .rpm - does not list any tools

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing `--requires` and `--whatrequires`. The first one will list packages required by package specified, whereas the second one will tell you which packages require given package (or other provided metadata/files).

You should use **--requires**